# Why does my Dmgcanvas installer window contain additional files?

Tags: macos, installation

Ive been using DMGCanvas to provide mac installer for my application for some years.

Previously when testing installer I click on the dmg, a window opens with my application and a shortcut to the Applications folder, the user just drags application to that folder.

But now there are additional dot folders listed:

.DS_Store
.background
.Trashes

in the window,

Within DMGCanvas applicatiom itself I cannot see these files, I don't know where they have come from or how to get rid of them, what do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was not a problem with DMGCanvas after all. I had forgotten that I had enabled show hidden files in Finder and that was why the dot files were visible.